# Logfile of SQL Server Database from Microsoft Dynamics 365 online

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365-v9

Is there a possibility to get the logfile of the SQL Server Database from Microsoft Dynamics 365 online Instance V9? I've already asked this question in the Microsoft Dynamics Community but haven't received any answers.

Comment: Probably only by contacting MS support.

Comment: I usually regret asking ....but....why do you need the DB TLog file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. In Dynamics 365 Online you even cannot get access to database backups, i.e. you cannot download or upload database backups.

Comment: While this is a true statement that you cannot get access to the database backups or the SQL database logfiles, Microsoft does provide Daily System Backups and a means to restore from those backups if needed to Dynamics 365 administrators.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/backup-restore-instances for details.